# Is it possible to see only the reviews that I did to my posts?

Tags: support, edits

Can you advice me on where I can find the answer to my question?

I would like to find every edit that I've been doing to my questions (on a specific site). Is it possible?

I know I can see the list of "edits" but it's comprehensive also of the edits made by other people. I would like to monitor just my effort in improving my questions..

Comment: @psubsee2003 That is actually incorrect. The "revisions" tab will also display *approved suggested edits* (because they are also edits attributed to the user).

Comment: @FEichinger you are correct, sorry, been a while and forgot the behavior.

Comment: Which question is it?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: sorry? do you mean my question is not clear?

Comment: In your post here you say "I would like to find every edit I've been doing to **the question** I've opened on a specific site." Which question is that referring to?

Comment: @TheGuywithTheHat: sorry. My english is terrible.. I will edit. Done. Hope now it's more clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to `http://[site]/users/[userID]/[username]?tab=activity&sort=revisions` (e.g. on this site it would be https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/256858/user3439274?tab=activity&sort=revisions for you) you can see all the edits you have done to any post. You can get there by going to your user page, clicking on the <kbd>activity</kbd> tab, then clicking on the <kbd>revisions</kbd> sub-tab.